# AWS APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent return CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, response

I have an AWS lambda which is triggered by an API Gateway. The lambda has to receive the request and generate a CSV file, which has to be returned to the user who sent the request. How can i attach my generated file to the APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postman for the test.  See video. https://studio.youtube.com/video/kxnSESgHuRM/edit

In Postman, you can go to the binary option and attach a file.

Comment: I want to send a GET request and receive the file, not upload it

Comment: This is late af on my part, but that is NOT what he asked for...!